# Is it possible to use Web site that can control our computer?

Tags: web-applications

Is it possible to use a website to control a computer, like [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) does?

If it is, which language would be the most suitable to create this kind of web application?

Comment: Yes, and it's been done. Check out http://gotomypc.com. As for language, anything which is network/gui aware would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely, by using such a service as [Join.me](http://join.me) which relies on Flash.